# Eloquent sum of derived column in select and also where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, subquery, aggregate

I have a table `sales` which has a related `receipts` table.

A sale can have many receipts. If the sum of the receipts is less than the sales amount then there is a balance outstanding.

I have the SQL that works just how I want. Having headaches trying to shoehorn this into eloquent.

```
        SELECT `sales`.`id`, `sales`.`created_at`,`sales`.`updated_at`,`sales`.`sales_date`,`sales`.`gross`,    `sales`.`net_amount`,`sales`.`vat_amount`,`sales`.`vat_rate`,`sales`.`description`,
            (SELECT SUM(receipt_gross_amount) as received_gross FROM `receipts` INNER JOIN `sales` WHERE `receipts`.`sales_id` = `sales`.`id`) as received
            FROM `sales`
        ) as unsettled_invoices
        WHERE unsettled_invoices.gross > COALESCE(unsettled_invoices.received,0)
```

I won't bore you with what I have tried already as it's not relevant and just causes php to hang and issue "killed" in the command line...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job ...

```
$unsettledsalessentries = DB::table('sales')
            ->leftjoin('receipts', 'sales.id','=', 'receipts.sales_id')
            ->select('sales.id','sales.gross','sales.description',DB::raw('SUM(COALESCE(receipts.receipt_gross_amount,0)) as total_receipts'))
            ->groupBy('sales.id','sales.gross','sales.description')
            ->havingRaw('sales.gross > total_receipts')
            ->get();
```